# How to insert data in arraylist in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jsp, arraylist

I've ajax callback function which in response receives a json object(arraylist parsed into json in another servlet) and iterates it.

ajax part:

```
$.ajax({
                     url:'ServiceToFetchDocType',
                     data: {"name":name},
                     type:'post',
                     cache:false,
                     success: function(response){

                         var select = $('#document_subtype');
                         select.find('option').remove();
                         $('<option value="">document_subtype</option>').appendTo(select);
                         $.each(response, function(index, value){
                             //insert the values into an array
                         });
                         callback.apply(select);
                     }                   

                 });
```

Now I want to insert the values into a string array. Any lead how to proceed on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [];
$.each(response, function(index, value){
 arr.push(value);
});
```

You could create a new array and push the values from your loop. If the values are strings, they will be stored as string otherwise you could call `value.toString()` while storing the same.

Comment: I've done this 
$.each(response, function(index, value){
              myArray.push(value);
              
             });

then 
for(var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)
               {
                alert(myArray[i]);
               }

but I'm getting no alerts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
    var arr = new Array();

     function keyval(key,val)
     {
        this.key = key;
        this.val = val;
     }
```

And in your function:

```
    var kv = new keyval(index,value);
    arr.push(kv);
```